# How to disable an input with jQuery Validation Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

This should be really simple but I can't get it to work, how do I disable and add a class to an input? Let's say I've got an input field with id = name, this is how far I got,

```
$("input#name").attr("disabled");
```

What am I doing wrong here? Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) a second parameter (the value to set, otherwise it *gets* the value), `true` in this case (`"disabled"` works too, but a boolean is desirable for a few reasons here):

```
$("input#name").attr("disabled", true).addClass('myClass');
```

[`.addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) then adds that class to the element.